# No tag for The 100

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Please create a tag for **the 100** TV Series of *The CW*. I have only 100 reps, and therefor I can't create one.

I need to ask a question on the 100.

Comment: Tag only got created when its needed. So if you have any question on it, ask it and leave a comment for the required tag, so that any high rep user will create it for u. For more details refer [here](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/406/why-are-there-no-tags-for-famous-franchises)

Answer (score 1):

Tags can only exist if they have at least 1 question asked for them. They can't be created on their own, only by asking a question and just adding the tag to it. So just feel free to ask your question right away. If you don't have enough reputation to add the tag, just leave a comment under the question asking for it and someone with enough reputation will eventually add the tag for you. (Afterall, they'll usually even do it if you don't leave a message, but that's the most secure way.)